# How to clear my deleted In-App Purchases in iTunesConnect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have many mistake In-App Purchase in iTunesConnect that I don't want. They only show as "Deleted" but appear. How to clear or hide them.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOf5Z.png)

Comment: How is this related to programming at all?

Answer (score 1):

It has answered so many times. 
Go to Account->Purchased and click delete that you don't want.

Comment: Where is Account->Purchased in iTunesConnect @Zoedia?